# Animate the fill of a rectangle diagonally?

Tags: html, css, svg

### Problem statement:

I created an animation of a clip-path disappearing from left to right

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect width="1" height="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

**Now I would like to do the same but rotated by an arbitrary angle**

Kind of like this, but it's clip-path which should be rotated

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect width="1" height="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <g transform="rotate(-30 50 50)" clip-path="url(#myClip)">
    <rect transform="rotate(30 50 50)" x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15"  />
  </g>
</svg>
```

### What I have tried:

Rotating `<rect>` - it skews the rect

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect transform="rotate(30)" width="1" height="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

Changing `scaleX` to `scale` and changing `transform-origin` - not an expected effect

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 100% 70%;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: 100% 70%;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect width="1" height="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

Wrapping `rect` with `g` so it can be rotated independently - everything disappears

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip rect {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <g>
      <rect width="1" height="1" />
    </g>
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can not use a group inside a clipPath.  Check here the permited content inside clipPath: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath#usage_notes

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve the desired result is to use a [CSS clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
This way, you can clip your rectangle with the border-radius and animate a pseudo element to fill the shape with the desired angle.

Note that the pseudo element should be larger than the square so it fills it up completly for every angle you choose. Here is an example :

```css
:root {
  --rotate-angle : 52deg; /** Change this to the desired angle **/
}

.sq {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-clip-path: path("M20,0 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z");
  clip-path: path("M20,0 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z");
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sq::before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -25%;
  top: -25%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #000;
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate-angle)) translatex(-100%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate-angle)) translatex(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate-angle)) translatex(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate-angle)) translatex(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sq"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I can't see anything though

Comment: @Konrad indeed, it worked in FF but it seems chrome doesn't support the round feature in the inset command. I edited the code using a the path command for the `clip-path`. It should work fine in chrome now.

Comment: Yes, it's working now, great job 

Answer (score 1):

You can animate a line in a [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask). The stroke-width and the translation values need to be adjusted a bit depending on the rotation/angle.

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#l1 {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 2px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, -2px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <mask id="m1" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <g transform="rotate(45)">
      <line id="l1" x2="2" transform="translate(0 0)" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" />
    </g>
  </mask>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" mask="url(#m1)" />
</svg>
```